# Beautiful Soup decode string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract and decode a phone number from :

```
<script>eval(unescape("document.write('%u003c%u0062%u0072%u003e%u003c%u0064%u0069%u0076%u0020%u0063%u006c%u0061%u0073%u0073%u003d%u0022%u0074%u0065%u006c%u0065%u0066%u006f%u006e%u006f%u0073%u0022%u003e%u0020%u003c%u0069%u006d%u0067%u0020%u0077%u0069%u0064%u0074%u0068%u003d%u0022%u0031%u0032%u0022%u0020%u0068%u0065%u0069%u0067%u0068%u0074%u003d%u0022%u0031%u0030%u0022%u0020%u0073%u0072%u0063%u003d%u0022%u0068%u0074%u0074%u0070%u003a%u002f%u002f%u0038%u0039%u002e%u0032%u0030%u0032%u002e%u0031%u0036%u0032%u002e%u0036%u0030%u002f%u0069%u006d%u0061%u0067%u0065%u006e%u0065%u0073%u002f%u0074%u0065%u0066%u002e%u0067%u0069%u0066%u0022%u003e%u0036%u0033%u0036%u0030%u0034%u0039%u0039%u0031%u0038%u003c%u002f%u0064%u0069%u0076%u003e')"))</script>
```

How i can decode and extract the phone number (636049918)?

Thank you!

Comment: You'd have to execute the obfuscated Javascript, something that BeautifulSoup cannot do for you.

Comment: Using [http://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=url&action=decode&charset=iso_8859_1](http://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=url&action=decode&charset=iso_8859_1) i can perfectly see the phone number.

Comment: Yes, because your browser executed the JS code.

Comment: It's not JS. Decode string is : <br><div class="telefonos"> <img width="12" height="10" src="http://89.202.162.60/imagenes/tef.gif">636049918</div>

Comment: If you only need to support this particular example, why do you need BeautifulSoup? In the general case, this requires a JavaScript interpreter. In the less general case, it depends. What are your boundary conditions?

Comment: The encoded string is from BS4 : print (soup.find("script"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = "%u003c%u0062%u0072%u003e%u003c%u0064%u0069%u0076%u0020%u0063%u006c......"
s = s.replace("%", "\\")

print s.decode('unicode-escape')
```

And to parse the number:

```
s = "%u003c%u0062%u0072%u003e%u003c%u0064%u0069%u0076%u0020%u0063%u006c......"
s = s.replace("%", "\\")

html = s.decode('unicode-escape')
html = BeautifulSoup(html)

print html.find("img").text
```

Comment: How i can extract the phone number from decoded string?

Comment: No problem. I have added that in an edit. Remember to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: You could do a try/except block, and use "pass" in the except block.